# IntelliJ IDEA can't run Scala test

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, maven-scala-plugin

My project is maven 3 based, mixed Java and Scala.

I can't run scalaTest in IDEA, IDEA complained:

```
Error:scala: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException
  at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:167)
  at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:178)
  at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:132)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.SbtCompiler.compile(SbtCompiler.scala:74)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

I tried to invalidate cache and restart IDEA , but can't solve this problem, can someone provide some help? thansk

---

more information:

Scala plugin's version is 2016.3.744

Scala version is 2.12.1.

maven configed with scala-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
             <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with a sample to reproduce and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) file.

Comment: Have created a [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11399) for the problem, check it out.